# Instant Status with Vera / ZWP-WS-100

Tags: lighting, smart-home

I have a light switch that I would like to control a Z-Wave outlet (GE) that is not on the load circuit for that switch (Old house, outlets aren't directly wired)

I've got a Vera Lite home control unit and have purchased a number of switches (GE / Leviton / ZWP) the last two claiming to support "Instant Status" — But in all cases I end up waiting for vera to "poll" my switch (sometimes this takes as long as 5 minutes) before the scene activates... Is there a way to make this work?

I'm looking to trigger a scene from a light switch without a huge delay. Regardless of the members in the scene, it seems that toggling light switches on Vera (even the new version "Instant Status" models) doesn't actually trigger any scenes.

Update:  Spoke with Vera support and they are stumped.  The ZWP supports instant on through a concept called "Central Scene Controller" however switching out device implementation file for that type doesn't actually work.